# How to compile C in both Linux and Solaris?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, compilation, solaris

I want to make a Makefile to can compile both in Linux and in Solaris.
I know how to do so individually, but how can I combine both and be able to detect what kind of OS I am using?
I am trying to do this for just a simple C file - but it is the name of the compiler that changes.

Comment: Are you sure you need to?  Are you using gcc on both?

Comment: @Foon I just know that to compile in Linux I do gcc or g++ and in Solaris I do cc. Or am I wrong about it?

Comment: there's a chance that there is a `cc` (or `c99`, or `c89` if you're old-fashioned) that is a link to `gcc` on Linux.  There's also a good chance that the default compiler is selected correctly on each platform by the default rules built into `make`.

Comment: Indeed, `$(CC)` should be the default compiler...

Comment: as folks above mentioned, on Linux cc is probably a symlink to gcc (and g++ / c++ are also symlinks to the same file on my box; I don't know if the executable does anything different depending on the program name (a la busybox) or (and I expect this is the case) varies based on the extensions of the targets and compiler options

Answer (score 5):

[GNU Autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) was designed to solve this very problem:

> Autoconf is an extensible package of
>   M4 macros that produce shell scripts
>   to automatically configure software
>   source code packages. These scripts
>   can adapt the packages to many kinds
>   of UNIX-like systems without manual
>   user intervention. Autoconf creates a
>   configuration script for a package
>   from a template file that lists the
>   operating system features that the
>   package can use, in the form of M4
>   macro calls.

I've used Autoconf myself for a couple of simple projects.  You can have a look at the source code to see how to use Autoconf for simple feature detection:

- [count](http://sourceforge.net/projects/count/)

Note that the purpose of Autoconf is not to detect your operating system.  Rather, it's designed to detect features, settings, etc. that may or may not be present on your operating system.

Think of asking the question "what is the C compiler called on this platform?" not "am I running on Linux or Solaris?"

Answer (score 0):

I am sure most people will say use some fancy autotools thing.  They are right of course.

But... you could put something like the following in your makefile.

```
OS = `uname -s`
ifeq ($(OS),Linux)
  ...
endif
ifeq ($(OS),Sun)
  ...
endif
```

Comment: I have seen the pain this approach causes.  Imagine you want to support a new OS under this system.  You'll have to go through and manually expand your Makefile logic to cope ... and you'll have to remember which OS supports which features, and hope they never change.  I've maintained a large application built with this approach, and it was a nightmare.  Autoconf is hard to learn, but well worth the effort.  Detect features, not operating systems!