# How to compile a 'C' application on Linux which compiles and runs fine on Solaris?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, solaris, oracle-pro-c

I am trying to compile and run a 'C' application on Linux which is running perfectly on Solaris. I first tried to just copy the binary file compiled on Solaris and run on Linux, but that gave me an error saying `cannot execute binary file`.
Hence I tried to first compile the code on Linux with the same Makefile which was used to compile it on Solaris. Contents of the Makefile are as follows:

```
PROC=$(ORACLE_HOME)/bin/proc
CFLAGS:=$(CFLAGS) -DSOLARIS
PROCFLAGS:=$(PROCFLAGS) -DSOLARIS
HEADERS= $(HOME)
target = $(HOME)
CC=gcc

%.c :%.ec ; $(PROC) $(PROCFLAGS) \
    INCLUDE=/usr/topendurc/inc \
    iname=$< oname=$(@F)

%.o :%.c ; $(CC) -I$(HEADERS) -DORA_PROC -c $(CFLAGS) \
    -L /usr/local/lib -L ./ -I /usr/local/include $<



MAKEC= mv $(target)/$(@F) $(target)/$(@F).old; \
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -lnsl -lsocket -lm  $^ -L $(target) \
    -L $(ORACLE_HOME)/lib -l clntsh \
    -o $(target)/$(@F)

$(target)/%:%.o  $(CLIBFILES); $(MAKEC)
%:%.o  $(CLIBFILES); $(MAKEC)

all: rm_interface clean

rm_interface: lrfunc.o tcp.o trace.o global.o rmi.o license.o purge.o fetch_data.o

clean:
    -rm lrfunc.o tcp.o trace.o global.o rmi.o purge.o license.o fetch_data.o trace.c global.c rmi.c
```

By using the above Makefile I got errors in the code as mentioned below:

```
gcc -I/home/dev1o -DORA_PROC -c  -DSOLARIS \
-L /usr/local/lib -L ./ -I /usr/local/include global.c
/home/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin/proc  -DSOLARIS \
INCLUDE=/usr/topendurc/inc \
iname=rmi.ec oname=rmi.c

Pro*C/C++: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Jan 16 13:19:57 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from:     /home/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

make: *** [rmi.c] Segmentation fault
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
global.c: In function `timeout_timer':
global.c:556: error: invalid application of `sizeof' to incomplete type `itimerval'
global.c:558: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
global.c:559: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
global.c:561: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
global.c:562: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
global.c:564: error: `ITIMER_REAL' undeclared (first use in this function)
global.c:564: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
global.c:564: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [global.o] Error 1
```

**UPDATE:**
Later I included a header file in the file `global.ec` and the errors got reduced to the following:

```
/home/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin/proc  -DSOLARIS \
    INCLUDE=/usr/topendurc/inc \
    iname=global.ec oname=global.c
/home/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin/proc  -DSOLARIS \
    INCLUDE=/usr/topendurc/inc \
    iname=rmi.ec oname=rmi.c

Pro*C/C++: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Jan 16 15:05:26 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from:     /home/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

make: *** [global.c] Segmentation fault
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Pro*C/C++: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Jan 16 15:05:26 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


System default option values taken from:     /home/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

make: *** [rmi.c] Segmentation fault
```

**Note:** The errors are being reported in the .c file but they are actually .ec files.

**Simplified version of global.ec**

```
#ifdef ORA_PROC
    #include "xxxoracle.h"
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stropts.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <unistd.h> 

EXEC SQL INCLUDE sqlca;
#define MILLION 1000000

/*connect to oracle database */ 
int
access_database(void)
{   
    char str[200]="";
    EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
        char ospasswd = '/';
        char dbname[40];
    EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;


    if (getenv("DBNAME") != 0)
        strcpy (dbname, (char *) getenv("DBNAME"));
    else
    {
        trace("Error ENV variable DBNAME not defined");
        return(1);
    }

    #ifdef ORA_PROC
        if (strlen(dbname) == strcspn(dbname, "/"))
            /* connect to database using Unix/OS password*/
            EXEC SQL connect :ospasswd using :dbname;
        else
            EXEC SQL connect :dbname;
        EXEC SQL ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS';
    #endif
    if (sqlca.sqlcode)
    {
        sprintf(str, "access_database(): Error connecting to database\0");
        return(1);
    }
    else
    {
        sprintf(str, "access_database(): Connecting to database");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Someone had asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488023/how-to-compile-c-in-both-linux-and-solaris) and the response that was accepted was to use **GNU Autoconf**. But I feel that in my case some changes in the Makefile or by adding some missing header files can make it work as everything is working on Solaris. 
I also found a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089203/segmentataion-fault) on StackOverflow and people have suggested to use a debugger like GDB. Will using GDB help in my case?

Please help me as I am very new to this.

Comment: The file `global.c` *do* include the headers needed for the `itimerval` structure and `ITIMER_REAL` macro?

Comment: That it works on one OS is no guarantee it will work on another. As someone once said: "There are no portable programs, only programs that have been ported".

Comment: This won't solve (I'd say the first problem is a scaring `segmentation fault` and that you must first investigate about that - then it seems some struct decl are missing, so maybe an include file is missing in your include directives), but I'd remove `-DSOLARIS`, it defines a symbol which suggests something that it's false

Comment: then, you will try to link with libs that are not on linux (since functions they provide are elsewhere), namely `-lnsl -lsocket` can be removed

Comment: @ShinTakezou You do realize that it's not the code in question that segfaults (since it hasn't even been compiled), but the compiler itself?

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes. Do you realize I realized it and this is why I find it "scary", since that a segfault in code one is developing is something that can happen very more likely - but a segfault in the tools we use to develop is "surprising"?

Comment: It appears that `Pro*C` is the tool that's segfaulting. I'm not familiar with that tool, but I don't think it's technically a compiler. Can we chase this down to a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org) of using `Pro*C` to pre-process a simplified version of `global.ec` and failing?

Comment: You can produce C code with Pro*C on Solaris, where you say it works. And then compile only C sources on Linux machine.

Comment: @Beta: I have added the simplified version of global.ec file. Please see if that helps.

Comment: And running `Pro*C` on that version of `global.ec` succeeds on Solaris but fails on Linux?

Comment: @Beta: Yes. It got compiled on Solaris and again gave segmentation fault on Linux.

Comment: Will using a debugger like GDB be helpful in my case?

Comment: A debugger can be a great help if you know what you are doing. It can be a gigantic waste of time if you don't. I'm leaning towards the latter based on the discussion so far.

Comment: Even if you were an expert in GDB, it probably wouldn't be of any use in this case.

Comment: @divanov, the resulting C code is probably intimately dependent on whatever shared library it uses to frob the Oracle database. If the Solaris and Linux databases aren't the exactly same version, all bets are off. And even so, I wouldn't like to have to depend on the result...

Comment: @MKSingh, better start with non-parallel compilation `make -j1`; you'll have to sort compilation issue out of multi-process aspects for your compiler. Did you try to call the compiler alone (without make) ? Did it compile another file of yours (like lrfunc.c or tcp.c) ?

Answer (score 0):

Using GDB will not help.  Your `make` process is experiencing a 'segmentation fault' error while trying to create the target file:`global.c`.  Any `*.ec` file in the same directory of the `Makefile` will be used to create a corresponding `*.c` file thru the use of the `Pro*C` tool (as prescribed by the Makefile).  This stage of building your `rm_interface` is definitely failing.  Most likely, the `global.c` file is not created, or malformed, which means you will not have the required prerequisites to build your final executable, which means you have nothing to debug with GDB.  You need to find out why the `Pro*C` tool is unable to create `global.c` from `global.ec` using this command:

```
/home/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin/proc  -DSOLARIS \
    INCLUDE=/usr/topendurc/inc \
    iname=global.ec oname=global.c
```

To investigate this, please use the suggestions already listed in the comments to the original question:

- Remove `-DSOLARIS`, suggested by [ShinTakezou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354803/shintakezou), OR replace with something more appropriate: `-DLINUX`, etc.
- Familiarize yourself with the Pro*C tool and it's options/arguments:  [ProC/C++ programmers guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14407/pc_10opt.htm#g30455)